# Proper way to replace service in Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I am developing a [helper library for EF Core](https://github.com/Giorgi/EntityFramework.Exceptions/) and currently it works by providing a custom `DbContext` class but I want to add a way to use it without a custom base class. I can achieve it by inheriting from [StateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.internal.statemanager) and telling EF to use my implementation for `IStateManager`.

I found two options for telling EF to use my implementation:

The first one is simply calling [DbContextOptionsBuilder.ReplaceService Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.replaceservice?view=efcore-2.1).

Second way is to cast `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to `IDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure`, call `AddOrUpdateExtension` on it, pass an `IDbContextOptionsExtension` instance and in `ApplyServices` method call `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped` method.

Out of these two options which one is a preferred ? Is there any difference between these two approaches?

Comment: So which way did you end up doing this?

Comment: @Botis I ended up using DbContextOptionsBuilder.ReplaceService Method.